# how to use ctrl-D in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash shell script that requires ctrl-D to break out of the terminal.can anyone tell me how to use it in the shell script

### example

ssh host last --->displays the list of users who were logged on to that host

I have different hosts the output is appended to one final and when I'm executing this particular shell script along with other series of commands, i'm using ctrl-D to see the output

suppose my shell script is myscript.sh
to execute myscript.sh

> ./myscript.sh

ctl-D

connection to host closed

output is displayed

Instead, I want to use ctrl-D in my script file

Answer (score 10):

You could try `exec <&-`
`&-` is used to close a file descriptor (ps:everything in linux is a kind of file...)
`<&-` is closing file descriptor 0 = stdin - can also be written as `0<&-`

If you open a normal terminal in your linux machine and type `exec <&-` you will see your terminal to close/dissapear like if you press `^D.`

PS1: Similarly, `exec >&-` closes stdout

PS2: If you close stdin with `exec <&-` you can re-open to continue your script with something like  `exec </dev/tty`

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do this directly. Use a heredoc to feed stdin instead.

```
./someprog.sh << EOF
something here
EOF
```

Comment: @Abrams thanks, but i tried executing the above cmd  i'm getting this ? EOF Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. >  can you tell me wats happening thanks

Answer (score 3):

To detect Ctrl-D in scripts and run custom logic on it you can read input char by char and check if char key code corresponds to Ctrl-D.

Here is a code example:

```
IFS=
while true; do
    read -n 1 key
    line=$line$key
    printf -v key_code "%d" "'$key"
    if [ $key_code -eq 4 ]; then
        echo "Ctrl-D pressed!"
    fi
    if [ "$key" = '' ]; then
        echo "Line was $line"
        line=
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
read  Input
#When ^D is used, read ends up with the exit code "1"
if [[ $? == 1 ]]
then 
     echo "[Ctrl+D] is captured"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/sh
echo 'Enter one line at a time'
echo 'Press CTRL+D to finish'
cat >test.out
echo 'OK'
```

Comment: This works because `cat` is a separate process, the CTRL-D hits that instead of your script, kills it, and returns control.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you tell `last` how many lines you want to see? Then you won't have to interrupt it with a Ctrl+D. For example, to see 10 lines use:

```
ssh hostname "last -10"
```